# Dynamically load icons on MainFrame

Tags: vb6

I have a problem when trying to load a main frame icon dynamically from my old VB6 application. The icon file has 2 icons 16x16x256 and 32x32x256 and I'm doing it via this simple way:

```
Private Sub Form_OnLoad()
   Me.Icon = LoadPicture("C:\MainMyIcon.ico")
End Sub
```

On the windows task bar the icon looks good, however on the main frame the icon is shown with only 16 (or may be less) colors.

What is most interesting if I load that icon via VB IDE the icon looks smooth and nice.

[LoadPicture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264946(v=vs.60).aspx) has several parameters, the 3rht is ColorDepth. I tried to set it manually to vbLPColor, which should be 256 colors, but the result is same.

Then I tried to load the Icon from Resources via [LoadResPicture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa244130(v=vs.60).aspx) , but again no luck for me.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you resort to Windows API, then the result looks good also with 256 colors:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function LoadImage Lib "user32" Alias "LoadImageA" (ByVal hInst As Long, ByVal lpsz As String, ByVal dwImageType As Long, ByVal dwDesiredWidth As Long, ByVal dwDesiredHeight As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessageLong Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Private Const LR_LOADFROMFILE = &H10
Private Const WM_SETICON = &H80
Private Const IMAGE_ICON = &H1
Private Const ICON_SMALL = &H0
Private Const ICON_BIG = &H1

Private Sub SetIconFromFile(ByVal hWnd As Long, FullFileName As String)
    Dim hIcon As Long
    hIcon = LoadImage(App.hInstance, FullFileName, IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_LOADFROMFILE)
    If hIcon = 0 Then Exit Sub
    SendMessageLong hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, hIcon
    SendMessageLong hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, hIcon
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    SetIconFromFile Me.hWnd, App.Path & "\" & "icon8bpp.ico"
End Sub
```

Here is a comparison with an icon with 256 total paletted colors. `Me.Icon` is dithering to 16.

[image]

Comment: Hi,

This was exactly my solution. Via Win32 I'm able to load 32 bit icons and everything is fine except that - Form.Icon property is no longer valid. So i had to replace all occurrences of 

MyForm_Load() : Me.Icon = frmMain.Icon 
....
with 
MyForm_Load() : SetFrameIcon Me

SetFrameIcon(ByRef frm As variant) sets the icon to a target form.